# I need to get 5/8" into the framing 3" high at the base of my wall framing; Is there an easy way to do this?

Tags: walls, framing

In the picture below I need to push the shower base like 5/8" into the frame at the top of the picture
The shower base is 3" high
The framing is a mess as it hosts the piping for the old shower and sink and a big now empty space after I relocated an air vent
[image]

I need this because a preliminary attempt to see how the things fit together shows me that the cabinet overlaps the shower pane 5/8"
[image]
The shower base edge where the glass gets installed is 2 5/8" so I will be left with 2" to install the glass which could be tight

[image]

Update:
The installation instructions are here
https://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1185992_2.pdf
And here are some details relevant to what I am trying to do
It seems that I am going to have to rebuild the frame as pushing the base under and into the existing framing will not allow me to install the two sheets of drywall as instructed
[image]

Comment: Have you considered pushing your cabinetry into the drywall on the left? (Though the rendering implies that the drawer is hard against the wall...) Failing that, I'd put 5/8" saw kerfs into the framing with a circular saw and a sacrificial blade, then clean it up with an oscillating tool and chisels. Wear eye protection especially, as you're bound to hit nails.

Comment: it is already against the wall to the left
I am considering removing it completely and building it from scratch as I have way too many vertical studs there which I will have to drill to run the green pipe
I also need to remove the copper piping that I have there and reroute the piping toward the perpendicular wall to get to the shower and sink

Comment: I added some details that show that I might need to build a new thinner frame from scratch. See the updates

Comment: hmmm reading that again I am seeing furring strips there not a second layer of drywall so I guess creating that notch there might actually help