# Does the water resistant cement board installed overlapping/hiding the edge of a shower pan absorb water in time?

Tags: drywall, shower

Here is what the manufacturer recommends for installing your shower base
[image]

I would like to go further with this and create a notch in the studs so I can push the shower base 1/2" closer to the wall (I need this and I also think that using furring strips as the manufacturer recommends is not the best solution -puts some pressure on the cement board AND ruins the vertical of the wall as the bottom side of the sheet is pushed toward the shower instead of sitting parallel with the wall at the base)

Here is what  would like to do. IN this case I might add some BlueSkin between the wood and the shower base

My question is this:, overt time, doesnt the cement board get wet and absorbs water in contact with the shower pan?  I know there will be sealant and there will be a slope in the shower pan
[image]

**Update:** I am not familiar with the best type of drywall or sheet that I can put there and I want to know if there is one that is absolutely guaranteed that won't absorb water.
From the comments and the answers I have received so far I take it that there is no such a thing and going with the lesser evil is the only option

**Update2:** this is related to this [Question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/207287/i-need-to-get-5-8-into-the-framing-3-high-at-the-base-of-my-wall-framing-is-t)

Comment: Stop calling that drywall. :-)..  You want Hardie board or cement board and then RedGard or some other waterproof coating.

Comment: Yes you are correct.I could not remember the correct name

Comment: Drywall (greenboard) should not be used in a shower or bathtub enclosure. Cement board is not water resistant,  if you use cement board you need to coat it with a waterproof membrane.  I prefer to use denseshield as it is easier to work with then cement board and already has a waterproof barrier applied to it. There is no need to reinvent the wheel here, if your shower system is installed properly you won’t have problems with water absorption, thus you will not need to notch the studs.

Comment: Nice thing about concrete board is that it won't burn.  Be careful with the foam boards if you have any soldering going on!  Agree that it is porous and will wick water.  The most basic thing is to put poly up before concrete board as your water proof layer.  You could also do epoxy grout with non-porous tiles.  I'd go foam board - wedi/keri/etc.

Comment: Please clarify: How thick is the lip of the base that goes behind the backer? Do you want to push the base into the stud by 1/2in regardless? Will there be gap between back of backer and front of lip? And does the backer then hit the bottom of your pan, as drawn?

Comment: The specs of the shower base and the installation instructions are here:: https://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1185992_2.pdf  I do need that half of the inch as this is moving the glass on the opposite edge closer to the wall and give me room to install a cabinet adjacent to that glass. I am flexible on all the other details and I would pick any sugested solution but the 1/2" notch is a must

Comment: Do note: The furring strip in your first image is not supposed to be 1 single strip at the bottom to clear the tub/pan flange and cause the wall board to bend. It's supposed to go behind the entire run of wall board so that the board remains flat and you don't get a kick out at the bottom. (Note the use of "wall" board to represent any of the many varieties of wall covering products, I'm not referring to any specific one.)

Comment: Then I see no difference between furring and notching, since also as @FreeMan observes from step 9 of the instructions, the furring is over the full length.

Comment: To me that looks like creating a space were you can get humidity and mold

Answer (score 1):

Anything called “water resistant” I’m sure will absorb moisture over time, including cement board.

A quick Google search confirmed this:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cement_board#Advantages

Comment: It has to, the humidity will move toward the dry areas

Comment: is there anything water proof ?

Comment: @MiniMe  ...glass, plastic...

Comment: I mean something for this purpose, to install tiles on it, you know, to build a shower :-)